# Wifi Adapter(s) not working

Tags: wifi, drivers, pop-os

I recently made the switch to Linux, settling on pop!_os and currently running version 20.10.

I have however had troubles getting my wifi adapter working, I originally had a WF-2109M from Mercer, but after realizing the driver support for it and Linux is bad, I went out and got a tp-link TL-WN725N which boasted linux drivers.

Both devices work on the generic drivers but achieve max speeds of around 50KB/s which is ofcourse very slow. The drivers I found for the TL-WN725N all failed to compile at the "make" command. Here is the driver and the error messages below: https://github.com/ilnanny/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian

```
ian@pop-os:~/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian$ make all
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.8.0-7630-generic/build M=/home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-7630-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/core/rtw_ap.o
In file included from /home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/core/rtw_ap.c:22:
/home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/include/osdep_service.h:94:8: error: ‘struct timer_list’ has no member named ‘data’
   94 |  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
      |        ^~
/home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/include/osdep_service.h:95:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   95 |  init_timer(ptimer);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~
      |  _init_timer
In file included from /home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/include/rtw_ht.h:24,
                 from /home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/include/drv_types.h:36,
                 from /home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/core/rtw_ap.c:23:
/home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/include/wifi.h: At top level:
/home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/include/wifi.h:733: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
  733 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
      | 
In file included from /home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/include/wifi.h:23,
                 from /home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/include/rtw_ht.h:24,
                 from /home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/include/drv_types.h:36,
                 from /home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/core/rtw_ap.c:23:
./include/linux/ieee80211.h:1600: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 1600 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
      | 
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:290: /home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian/core/rtw_ap.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1780: /home/ian/Desktop/TL-WN725N-TP-Link-Debian] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-7630-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:147: modules] Error 2
```

a similar situation exist with this one(even though unsure if that's the correct driver): https://github.com/twd2/TL-WN725N-V2-Driver-for-Linux

See below some additional information which could be helpful:

```
ian@pop-os:~/Desktop/rtl8188eu$ dkms status
nvidia, 455.38, 5.8.0-7630-generic, x86_64: installed
system76, 1.0.11~1606243918~20.10~0ca551b, 5.8.0-7630-generic, x86_64: installed
system76_acpi, 1.0.2~1600812457~20.10~0bc966c, 5.8.0-7630-generic, x86_64: installed (original_module exists)
system76-io, 1.0.1~1559663713~20.10~ea5f61a, 5.8.0-7630-generic, x86_64: installed
```

```
ian@pop-os:~/Desktop/rtl8188eu$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04d9:fc15 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. USB Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 048: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 003 Device 049: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 003 Device 046: ID 05e3:0723 Genesys Logic, Inc. GL827L SD/MMC/MS Flash Card Reader
Bus 003 Device 045: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
ian@pop-os:~/Desktop/rtl8188eu$ lsmod | grep 8192
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
rtl8192cu              81920  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        61440  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                94208  3 rtl8192c_common,rtl_usb,rtl8192cu
mac80211              917504  4 rtl_usb,rtl8192cu,rtlwifi,rtl8xxxu
```

```
ian@pop-os:~/Desktop/rtl8188eu$ lsmod | grep 8188
r8188eu               438272  0
lib80211               16384  1 r8188eu
cfg80211              782336  4 rtlwifi,mac80211,rtl8xxxu,r8188eu
```

Comment: @roaima question edited

Comment: Should you have both the `rtl8192cu` and `r8188eu` drivers loaded at the same time? Feels strange to me

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with drivers inlinux, how do I go about disabling/enabling one?